# Scala : Normalize the second argument or a Map[String, Int]

Tags: scala, dictionary

I have a `Map[String, Int]` being (word, count) of a document. I would like to get a `Map[String, Double]` out of it by dividing (normalising) the second argument by the total count of each words.

How can I efficiently :

1. Sum the counts of each word in the map
2. Divide each count by the total_count found in (1.) ?

I cannot think of a "simple" way of doing it.

EDIT 1 : The way I am summing the counts is as following :

```
var total_count = 0
    for((x,y) <- s) yield {total_count += y}
```

EDIT 2 : The map looks like this :

```
[o’s c -> 1], [the c -> 1], [who’s -> 1], [ is a -> 2]
```

These are n-grams, not really "words" so to speak

Comment: The key is unique! The counts can be greater than 1 in the map

Comment: could you please add an example of your `Map` to clarify

Comment: ok, got it from your edit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the sum as a `Double` by doing `val total = map.values.sum.toDouble`.

You can then do `map.mapValues(_ / total)` to get a `Map[String, Double]`.

Be aware that `mapValues` is going to give you a *view* of your `map`.  That is, it stores references to the original `map` and to the lambda (`_ / total`) and computes values on-demand whenever you ask for them.

If you want to compute all of the `Double` values once, you can do `map.map({ case (k, v) => k -> (v / total) })` instead.

Finally, be aware that if your `Map[String, Int]` has no pairs in it, or all of the values are zero, then you will be dividing by zero.

Comment: you should `_.toDouble` first

Comment: @dk14 Just added that :)